# Cannot convert from List<Mono<BOLCompliance>> to List<BOLCompliance>

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I had a method createComplianceResponse() which was returning BOLCompliance object before which I changed to Mono of BOLCompliance as I had to call another reactive service inside it.
But after doing that, my current service from which I was making the call to this service is giving errors at line 6 and 7.

```
1) Cannot convert from Mono<Object> to Mono<List<BOLCompliance>>
2) Cannot convert from List<Mono<BOLCompliance>> to List<BOLCompliance>
```

```
    private Mono<List<BOLCompliance>> getComplienceRouteLink(BOLRouteLink routeLink, BillOfLadingResponse bol) {
        if (null != routeLink.getComplianceIds() && !routeLink.getComplianceIds().isEmpty()) {
            Mono<List<Compliance>> complianceList = Flux
                    .fromIterable(routeLink.getComplianceIds()).flatMap(cmp ->
                            complianceCaller.getComplianceById(cmp)).collectList();
            return complianceList.flatMap(compliancesOld -> {
                List<BOLCompliance> complianceResponses = compliancesOld.parallelStream()
                        .map(compliance -> createComplianceResponse(compliance,bol)
                        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
                return Mono.just(complianceResponses);
            });
        }
```

My other service for whom I changed return type is

```
private Mono<BOLCompliance> createComplianceResponse(Compliance compliance, BillOfLadingResponse bol);
```

Comment: you're mixing up things, I'd say.  You have a parellelStream in there, hinting that you want to parallelize the createComplianceResponse.  I think you should try to produce a Flux<BOLCompliance> instead of the Mono<List<BOLCompliance>>, leave out the parallelStream, and just map to createComplianceResponse().  This should then produce the Flux<BOLCompliance>, and be parrallelizable, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at this, which could replace your code:

```
private Flux<BOLCompliance> getComplienceRouteLink(BOLRouteLink routeLink, BillOfLadingResponse bol) {
    return Mono.justOrEmpty(routeLink.getComplianceIds())
        .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
        .flatMap(id -> complianceCaller.getComplianceById(id))
        .flatMap(compliance -> createComplianceResponse(compliance, bol));
}
```

Instead of returning a `Mono<List<Something>>` you return a `Flux<Something>` and can parallelize on that.  It's also important to know, what call might take longer, and needs to be scheduled on another threadpool, to be parallelized. You can extend this Flux creation with scheduling on another threadpool easily.

Comment: I'm getting: Cannot convert from Flux<Object> to Flux<BOLCompliance> on line 2 of the solution provided by you.  

return Mono.justOrEmpty(routeLink.getComplianceIds())

Comment: Thanks, I'm able to fix the error using flatMap() instead of map()

Comment: In your code or in mine? I'd like to fix my code snippet, if possible.

Comment: in yours not mine, yeah please fix it